# How to upload an artifact to an Azure DevOps build using the API

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

Can anyone shed some light on how to use the ADO API to upload an artifact to a build. I can't find an example that shows how to do this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/create

I know there is the vso task: ##vso[artifact.upload]local file path
But, I need to do this from another script and the vso task isn't available.

Thanks.